# Why is the factory method declared as protected?

Tags: java, design-patterns, keyword, factory-method

I'm reading the Head First Design Patterns book and on the "Declaring a factory method" section in Chapter 4, the method is declared as protected:

```
public abstract class PizzaStore {

    public Pizza orderPizza(String type) {
        Pizza pizza;
        pizza = createPizza(type);
        pizza.prepare(); // other methods follow

        return pizza;
    }

    protected abstract Pizza createPizza(String type);

}
```

This confuses me because I initially thought, in fact it is also stated in the book, that having a factory (method) allows you to have a single place that creates an instance for you, not just for acting on later but also for "querying".
By "acting on" I mean `pizza.cut()` etc, and by "querying" I mean `pizza.isSpicy()`.

Wouldn't the `protected` keyword limit the querying to only the subclasses and same-package classes? What if a 3rd-party class needed to know that the pizza is spicy before ordering?

I may be overthinking this, because the highlight box does not say it HAS to be `protected` but it's there in the sample code.

Comment: Not everyone who might answer this question has the book in front of them. This example is not complete enough for me to explain it. Please [edit] in more code.

Comment: *"protected abstract class Pizza createPizza(String type);"* ... I don't think that this is valid Java code.  It certainly isn't a protected method declaration.

Comment: @scottb my bad. no `class` keyword there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This confuses me because I initially thought, in fact it is also stated in the book, that having a factory (method) allows you to have a single place that creates an instance for you, not just for acting on later but also for "querying"

- If you wanted the client (that is, the calling code) to be in control of when a `Pizza` gets "created" then you wouldn't make the `createPizza` method protected; it would be a public method and anyone with a reference to an instance of `PizzaStore` could call it.
- If you think about that class, the semantics of `orderPizza` are clearly different from `createPizza` - the former deals with a caller asking for a resource, whereas the latter deals with obtaining that resource, whether this be creating a new one or re-using an old one.
- So in this case, it's clear that the `PizzaStore` class wants to retain control over when a pizza actually gets "created", and this is why it's protected. (also because a class that inherits from `PizzaStore` can also implement the method - if it were private it couldn't see it in order to implement it - and note that since it's abstract, a subclass *has* to implement it). So the creation process is (as Ananthu also mentioned) safely **encapsulated** within the store.

Let's suppose that the actual "creation" of a `Pizza` is a really expensive operation; we don't want just anyone to decide when it happens. Therefore by keeping the factory method protected, it allows the `PizzaStore` to make decisions such as (pseudo-code, I don't know Java) :

```
public abstract class PizzaStore {

    protected PizzaBin bin;

    //customer orders a pizza
    public Pizza orderPizza(String type) {
        //maybe we already have one...
        Pizza pizza = HeresOneWeMadeEarlier(type);
        if (pizza !=null) return pizza;
        //nope, we have none, so we have to make one.
        pizza = createPizza(type);
        pizza.prepare(); // other methods follow
        return pizza;
    }
    
    //customer returns a pizza
    public void ReturnPizza(Pizza pie) {
     if(!pie.HasAllSlices()){
       throw new CannotReturnPartiallyEatenPizzaException();
      }
     //hmm. maybe we can re-use this later on...
     bin.store(pie);        
    }
  
    //check if we have a pizza in the bin.
    protected Pizza HeresOneWeMadeEarlier(String type){
        if(bin.contains(type)){
          //we never said this was a *nice* pizza store!
            return bin.takeOutAndDustOff(type);
        }
        else{
          return null;
        }
    }

    protected abstract class Pizza createPizza(String type);

}
```

Maybe not a very nice place to get a Pizza, but I hope you see what I mean :)

> By "acting on" I mean pizza.cut() etc, and by "querying" I mean pizza.isSpicy().

Bear in mind that these are methods on a `Pizza`, not a `PizzaStore`, and so therefore they don't really come into play here - when the caller is given their `Pizza`, they will be able to call whatever public methods a `Pizza` has (`eat`, `cut`, `share`, etc.) and the `PizzaStore` probably doesn't have any interest in it any more.

Hope that helps.

#### Update

Just to address one point you had as well:

> What if a 3rd-party class needed to know that the pizza is spicy before ordering?

In that case, you'd design a method on `PizzaStore` that would give a list of ingredients or options, and whether or not they were spicy.

- Then when the client ordered a pizza (specifying a list of options), they already know if it's spicy based on the list of options they had.
- Another client, if they had the order number, would presumably be able to look up the details of the order, which includes the options chosen at the time the pizza was requested, and thus can also determine if the pizza is spicy or not.

Comment: LOL took me almost a year to mark your answer, but eh. I think I get it now, I was misunderstanding some foundations of it. Evidence: "What if a 3rd-party class needed to know that the pizza is spicy before ordering?"

Comment: Glad it finally makes sense! In terms of an external class knowing if a pizza was or wasn't spicy - see my updated answer

Comment: The createPizza method is an example of the Template Method pattern. Read about that for more information.